# Gatling jsonpath, save value

Tags: jsonpath, gatling

[image]I have a json response I want to obtain a value from looking like this:

```
{
"resourceType": "Parameters",
"parameter": [
{
  "name": "medication",
  "resource": {
    "resourceType": "Bundle",
    "id": "cfa4fa3c-0e34-431c-ac0d-91653ebda972",
    "meta": {
      "lastUpdated": "2022-09-23T11:37:49.6022504+02:00",
      "source": "http://xxx.xxx/Patient/$getMedication",
      "profile": [
        "http://xxxStructureDefinition/sfm-MedicationBundle"
      ]
    },
    "type": "document",
    "timestamp": "2022-09-23T11:37:49.6022471+02:00",
    "total": 6,
    "link": [
      {
        "relation": "self",
        "url": "http://xxx/Patient/$getMedication"
      }
    ],
    "entry": [
      {
        "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:fbb2bd18-a1c3-4f95-8384-d520fba283a5",
        "resource": {
          "resourceType": "Composition",
          "id": "dfc4f003-4eb6-4802-8b8a-d2d53cf7698c",
          "meta": {
            "profile": [
              "http://xxx/StructureDefinition/sfm-MedicationComposition"
            ]
          },
          "identifier": {
            "use": "official",
            "value": "28c2ae8d-39ed-4054-af46-22bc8c2c1e4a"
          },
          "status": "final",
          "type": {
            "coding": [
              {
                "system": "http://loinc.org",
                "code": "11503-0",
                "display": "Medical records"
              }
            ]
          },
          "subject": {
            "reference": "urn:uuid:67bb77c3-55dc-4643-b334-7f95e38bcf2f",
            "type": "http://xxx/StructureDefinition/sfm-Patient",
            "display": "Patient 05129997836"
          },
          "date": "2022-09-23",
          "author": [
            {
              "reference": "urn:uuid:a443c8b2-a45a-4bad-baa6-f38904363673",
              "type": "http://xxx/StructureDefinition/sfm-Practitioner",
              "display": "xxx xxx, HPR: xxx"
            }
          ],
          "title": "Medication summary",
          "confidentiality": "N",
          "section": [
            {
              "title": "Medication",
              "code": {
                "coding": [
                  {
                    "system": "http://xxx/CodeSystem/sfm-section-types",
                    "code": "sectionMedication",
                    "display": "List of Medication statements"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "text": {
                "status": "generated",
                "div": "<xhtml:div xmlns:xhtml=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">List of medications</xhtml:div>"
              },
              "entry": [
                {
                  "reference": "urn:uuid:8c714f72-0c90-403d-9e80-b08c61f82068",
                  "type": "http://xxx/fhir/StructureDefinition/sfm-MedicationStatement",
                  "display": "Paracetamol tab 1 g"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "title": "PllInfo",
              "code": {
                "coding": [
                  {
                    "system": "http://xxx/fhir/CodeSystem/sfm-section-types",
                    "code": "sectionPLLinfo",
                    "display": "PLL Info"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "text": {
                "status": "generated",
                "div": "<xhtml:div xmlns:xhtml=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Nil Known</xhtml:div>"
              },
              "emptyReason": {
                "coding": [
                  {
                    "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/list-empty-reason",
                    "code": "nilknown",
                    "display": "Nil Known"
                  }
                ],
                "text": "Nil Known"
              }
            },
            {
              "title": "Allergies",
              "code": {
                "coding": [
                  {
                    "system": "http://xxx/fhir/CodeSystem/sfm-section-types",
                    "code": "sectionAllergies",
                    "display": "Section allergies"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "text": {
                "status": "generated",
                "div": "<xhtml:div xmlns:xhtml=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Nil Known</xhtml:div>"
              },
              "emptyReason": {
                "coding": [
                  {
                    "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/list-empty-reason",
                    "code": "nilknown",
                    "display": "Nil Known"
                  }
                ],
                "text": "Nil Known"
              }
            },
            {
              "title": "Other Prescriptions",
              "code": {
                "coding": [
                  {
                    "system": "http://xxx/fhir/CodeSystem/sfm-section-types",
                    "code": "sectionOtherPrescriptions",
                    "display": "List of non medical prescriptions"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "text": {
                "status": "generated",
                "div": "<xhtml:div xmlns:xhtml=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Nil Known</xhtml:div>"
              },
              "emptyReason": {
                "coding": [
                  {
                    "system": "http://terminology.hl7.org/CodeSystem/list-empty-reason",
                    "code": "nilknown",
                    "display": "Nil Known"
                  }
                ],
                "text": "Nil Known"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:a443c8b2-a45a-4bad-baa6-f38904363673",
        "resource": {
          "resourceType": "Practitioner",
          "id": "1571880245",
          "meta": {
            "profile": [
              "http://xxx/fhir/StructureDefinition/sfm-Practitioner"
            ]
          },
          "identifier": [
            {
              "use": "official",
              "type": {
                "coding": [
                  {
                    "system": "http://hl7.no/fhir/NamingSystem/HPR",
                    "code": "HPR-nummer"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "system": "urn:oid:2.16.578.1.12.4.1.4.4",
              "value": "10055817"
            },
            {
              "use": "official",
              "type": {
                "coding": [
                  {
                    "system": "http://hl7.no/fhir/NamingSystem/FNR",
                    "code": "FNR-nummer"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "system": "urn:oid:2.16.578.1.12.4.1.4.1",
              "value": "10099205569"
            }
          ],
          "active": true,
          "name": [
            {
              "use": "official",
              "family": "xxx",
              "given": [
                "xxx"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "gender": "male",
          "birthDate": "1992-09-10"
        }
      },
      {
        "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:67bb77c3-55dc-4643-b334-7f95e38bcf2f",
        "resource": {
          "resourceType": "Patient",
          "id": "873788333",
          "meta": {
            "profile": [
              "http://xxx/fhir/StructureDefinition/sfm-Patient"
            ]
          },
          "identifier": [
            {
              "use": "official",
              "type": {
                "coding": [
                  {
                    "system": "http://hl7.no/fhir/NamingSystem/FNR",
                    "code": "FNR-nummer"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "system": "urn:oid:2.16.578.1.12.4.1.4.1",
              "value": "05129997836"
            }
          ],
          "active": true,
          "name": [
            {
              "family": "05129997836",
              "given": [
                "Patient"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "gender": "female",
          "birthDate": "1999-12-05",
          "address": [
            {
              "type": "postal",
              "text": "Autoveien 1",
              "city": "Oslo",
              "postalCode": "0150"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:f4c95e15-8e9f-416a-83c7-3a6847d69278",
        "resource": {
          "resourceType": "Practitioner",
          "id": "1215535826",
          "meta": {
            "profile": [
              "http://xxx/fhir/StructureDefinition/sfm-Practitioner"
            ]
          },
          "identifier": [
            {
              "use": "official",
              "type": {
                "coding": [
                  {
                    "system": "http://hl7.no/fhir/NamingSystem/HPR",
                    "code": "HPR-nummer"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "system": "urn:oid:2.16.578.1.12.4.1.4.4",
              "value": "1010038"
            }
          ],
          "active": true,
          "name": [
            {
              "extension": [
                {
                  "url": "http://hl7.no/fhir/StructureDefinition/no-basis-middlename",
                  "valueString": "Psa"
                }
              ],
              "use": "official",
              "family": "xx",
              "given": [
                "xx"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "gender": "male"
        }
      },
      {
        "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:4b4de0ae-3f2d-4030-a193-26713cf30260",
        "resource": {
          "resourceType": "Medication",
          "id": "667718723",
          "meta": {
            "profile": [
              "http://xxx/fhir/StructureDefinition/sfm-Medication"
            ]
          },
          "extension": [
            {
              "extension": [
                {
                  "url": "prescriptiongroup",
                  "valueCodeableConcept": {
                    "coding": [
                      {
                        "system": "urn:oid:2.16.578.1.12.4.1.1.7421",
                        "code": "C",
                        "display": "Reseptgruppe C"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ],
              "url": "http://hl7.no/fhir/StructureDefinition/no-basis-prescriptiongroup"
            },
            {
              "extension": [
                {
                  "url": "registreringstype",
                  "valueCodeableConcept": {
                    "coding": [
                      {
                        "system": "http://xxx/fhir/CodeSystem/sfm-festregistrationtype",
                        "code": "1",
                        "display": "Legemiddelvirkestoff"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ],
              "url": "http://xxx/fhir/StructureDefinition/sfm-medicationdetails"
            }
          ],
          "identifier": [
            {
              "use": "official",
              "type": {
                "text": "identifier"
              },
              "value": "ID_DF40453A-DAD1-450D-A58D-0FE411DCDB05"
            }
          ],
          "code": {
            "coding": [
              {
                "system": "http://xxx/fhir/CodeSystem/FEST",
                "code": "ID_DF40453A-DAD1-450D-A58D-0FE411DCDB05",
                "display": "Paracetamol tab 1 g"
              },
              {
                "system": "http://www.whocc.no/atc",
                "code": "N02BE01",
                "display": "Paracetamol"
              }
            ]
          },
          "status": "active",
          "form": {
            "coding": [
              {
                "system": "urn:oid:2.16.578.1.12.4.1.1.7448",
                "code": "53",
                "display": "Tablett"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "fullUrl": "urn:uuid:8c714f72-0c90-403d-9e80-b08c61f82068",
        "resource": {
          "resourceType": "MedicationStatement",
          "id": "1850837775",
          "meta": {
            "profile": [
              "http://xxx/fhir/StructureDefinition/sfm-MedicationStatement"
            ]
          },
          "extension": [
            {
              "extension": [
                {
                  "url": "reseptdate",
                  "valueDate": "2022-09-21"
                },
                {
                  "url": "expirationdate",
                  "valueDate": "2023-09-20"
                },
                {
                  "url": "festUpdate",
                  "valueDateTime": "2022-08-25T13:54:02+00:00"
                },
                {
                  "url": "dssn",
                  "valueString": "1 tablett morgen daglig"
                },
                {
                  "url": "amount",
                  "valueQuantity": {
                    "value": 92.0,
                    "unit": "stk"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "url": "reit",
                  "valueString": "3"
                },
                {
                  "url": "itemgroup",
                  "valueCodeableConcept": {
                    "coding": [
                      {
                        "system": "urn:oid:2.16.578.1.12.4.1.1.7402",
                        "code": "L",
                        "display": "Legemiddel"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "extension": [
                    {
                      "url": "starttime",
                      "valueDate": "2022-09-21"
                    },
                    {
                      "extension": [
                        {
                          "url": "amount",
                          "valueQuantity": {
                            "value": 1.0,
                            "unit": "tablett"
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "url": "interval",
                          "valueQuantity": {
                            "value": 1.0,
                            "unit": "Døgn"
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "url": "accurate",
                          "valueBoolean": false
                        },
                        {
                          "url": "timerange",
                          "valueCodeableConcept": {
                            "coding": [
                              {
                                "system": "urn:oid:2.16.578.1.12.4.1.1.8325",
                                "code": "1",
                                "display": "Morgen"
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      ],
                      "url": "repeatingdosage"
                    }
                  ],
                  "url": "ereseptdosing"
                },
                {
                  "extension": [
                    {
                      "url": "status",
                      "valueCodeableConcept": {
                        "coding": [
                          {
                            "system": "urn:oid:2.16.578.1.12.4.1.1.7408",
                            "code": "E",
                            "display": "Ekspederbar"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "url": "rfstatus"
                },
                {
                  "url": "typeresept",
                  "valueCodeableConcept": {
                    "coding": [
                      {
                        "system": "urn:oid:2.16.578.1.12.4.1.1.7491",
                        "code": "E",
                        "display": "Eresept"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ],
              "url": "http://xxx/fhir/StructureDefinition/sfm-reseptamendment"
            },
            {
              "extension": [
                {
                  "url": "status",
                  "valueCodeableConcept": {
                    "coding": [
                      {
                        "system": "http://xxx/fhir/CodeSystem/sfm-medicationstatement-registration-status",
                        "code": "3",
                        "display": "Godkjent"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "url": "type",
                  "valueCodeableConcept": {
                    "coding": [
                      {
                        "system": "http://xxx/fhir/CodeSystem/sfm-performer-roles",
                        "code": "1",
                        "display": "Forskrevet av"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "url": "provider",
                  "valueReference": {
                    "reference": "urn:uuid:f4c95e15-8e9f-416a-83c7-3a6847d69278",
                    "type": "http://xxx/fhir/StructureDefinition/sfm-Practitioner",
                    "display": "Bjørn Psa Visjon, HPR: 1010038"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "url": "timestamp",
                  "valueDateTime": "2022-09-21T16:10:25.5229768+02:00"
                }
              ],
              "url": "http://xxx/fhir/StructureDefinition/sfm-regInfo"
            },
            {
              "extension": [
                {
                  "url": "genericSubstitutionAccepted",
                  "valueBoolean": true
                }
              ],
              "url": "http://xxx/fhir/StructureDefinition/sfm-generic-substitution"
            },
            {
              "extension": [
                {
                  "url": "nocombination",
                  "valueBoolean": false
                }
              ],
              "url": "http://xxx/fhir/StructureDefinition/sfm-administration"
            }
          ],
          "identifier": [
            {
              "use": "usual",
              "type": {
                "text": "ReseptId"
              },
              "value": "1dfa55d7-674d-4fc8-a182-1fbd3b2faa6a"
            }
          ],
          "status": "active",
          "medicationReference": {
            "reference": "urn:uuid:4b4de0ae-3f2d-4030-a193-26713cf30260",
            "type": "http://xxx/fhir/StructureDefinition/sfm-Medication",
            "display": "Paracetamol tab 1 g"
          },
          "subject": {
            "reference": "urn:uuid:67bb77c3-55dc-4643-b334-7f95e38bcf2f",
            "type": "http://xxx/fhir/StructureDefinition/sfm-Patient",
            "display": "Patient 05129997836"
          },
          "dosage": [
            {
              "extension": [
                {
                  "url": "http://xxx/fhir/StructureDefinition/sfm-use",
                  "valueCodeableConcept": {
                    "coding": [
                      {
                        "system": "urn:oid:2.16.578.1.12.4.1.1.9101",
                        "code": "1",
                        "display": "Fast"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "extension": [
                    {
                      "url": "text",
                      "valueString": "MOT SMERTER"
                    }
                  ],
                  "url": "http://xxx/fhir/StructureDefinition/sfm-application-area"
                }
              ],
              "sequence": 1,
              "text": "1 tablett morgen daglig"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "name": "KJHentetTidspunkt",
  "valueDateTime": "2022-09-23T09:37:49.55+00:00"
},
{
  "name": "RFHentetTidspunkt",
  "valueDateTime": "2022-09-23T11:37:49.027+02:00"
},
{
  "name": "KJFeilkode",
  "valueCodeableConcept": {
    "coding": [
      {
        "system": "http://xxx/fhir/CodeSystem/sfm-kj-rf-error-code",
        "code": "0"
      }
    ],
    "text": "OK"
  }
},
{
  "name": "RFM96Feilkode",
  "valueCodeableConcept": {
    "coding": [
      {
        "system": "http://xxx/fhir/CodeSystem/sfm-kj-rf-error-code",
        "code": "0"
      }
    ],
    "text": "OK"
  }
},
{
  "name": "RFM912Feilkode",
  "valueCodeableConcept": {
    "coding": [
      {
        "system": "http://xxx/fhir/CodeSystem/sfm-kj-rf-error-code",
        "code": "0"
      }
    ],
    "text": "OK"
  }
},
{
  "name": "KJHarLegemidler",
  "valueBoolean": false
},
{
  "name": "KJHarLaste",
  "valueBoolean": false
},
{
  "name": "RFHarLaste",
  "valueBoolean": false
}
 ]
 }
```

The value I am looking for is the "fullUrl", as in urn:uuid:fbb2bd18-a1c3-4f95-8384-d520fba283a5

I tried to use this jsonpath expression:
.check(jsonPath("$..[?(@.resourceType=="Bundle")].entry.fullUrl").saveAs("fullUrl"))

However it says

> jsonPath($..[?(@.resourceType=="Bundle")].entry.fullUrl).find.    exists, found nothing

How can I construct an experssion to obtain the fullUrl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `entry` is array. So you have two options how to extract the value.

1. You can get all `fullUrl` values and then obtain via Gatling EL:

```
jsonPath("$..[?(@.resourceType=='Bundle')].entry..fullUrl").findAll.saveAs("fullUrls")
```

And then just get by index `#{fullUrls(0)}` ([Documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/session/el/#syntax))

2. Or get by index in the json path:

```
                                                   |
                                                   |
                                                   ᐯ
 jsonPath("$..[?(@.resourceType=='Bundle')].entry.[0].fullUrl").findAll.saveAs("fullUrl")
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, but if I do your first suggestion I get a vector like this:

ullUrl:
Vector(urn:uuid:d535dc20-c4cc-43ff-8229-f5c41e770c9a, urn:uuid:7e02c406-aa34-42f9-9608-1e6a7d81ceb8...

But referencing it with:

    .exec(session=>{
      println("fullUrl:")
      println(session("#{fullUrl(0)}").as[String])
      session})


Gives me this:

'hook-1' crashed with 'j.u.NoSuchElementException: No attribute named '#{fullUrl(0)}' is defined'

Comment: @MagnusJensen maybe you did mistake `fullUrl` vs `fullUrls`

Comment: Also you can enable logs https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/guides/debugging/#logback and it shows all Session variables

Comment: Did enable logs but still having issues with referencing the "0" element in the vector I manage to save. I am referencing it with: 

 .exec(session=>{
      println("fullUrl:")
      println(session("#{fullUrl(0)}").as[String])
      session})

Comment: And, using  .check(jsonPath("$..[?(@.resourceType==\'Bundle')].entry.[0].fullUrl").saveAs("fullUrl"))

It says  jsonPath($..[?(@.resourceType=='Bundle')].entry.[0].fullUrl).find.exists extraction crashed: end of input expected

Comment: What did you see in logs? Was there your variable inside `Session` block?

Comment: Yes it is inside my session block looking like this: fullUrl -> Vector(urn:uuid:62f7ca8d-d486-42b4-b095-2d84b89ae757, urn:uuid:acfa1987-0904-4a6c-8efe-e65994106744, urn:uuid:2031d6de-6e64-411a-8102-72e7cae51f26,

Comment: Ok, we'll try another way) Run this:
`.exec(_.set("fullUrl", Vector("123", "456", "789")))
    .exec(session => {
      val fullUrl = session("fullUrl").as[Vector[String]]
      println(s"fullUrl: ${fullUrl(0)}")
      session
    }))`

It works?

Comment: added a picture, your other way does not work, aka the code is not correct? See picture added now.

Comment: This code correct and it works

Comment: Sorry, made it work. so it print this: fullUrl: 123

Comment: Now try to use this in your scenario